# Why does my dropdown keep returning the first item in the dropdown?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a dropdown in a vb.net application that is also using radwindow as it's modal. I have the dropdown databinding in the if not ispostback method, yet when I select a value and run it, it still returns the first item. I tried using autopostback set to true but doing that also closes the radwindow. Any other work arounds?

```
 <telerik:RadWindow RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="winComments" runat="server" Title="Comments" RestrictionZoneID="ContentTemplateZone" Modal="true" Width="600" Skin="Outlook"
                        Height="550" Animation="Fade" Left="600" Top="100" CenterIfModal="true" EnableShadow="true" EnableViewState="false">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <br />
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCommentVin" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                                    Department:
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartments" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" runat="server" Text="" Height="300px" Width="550px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>

                            <br />

                            <div class="col-md-offset-4">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/btnCancel.png" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" CssClass="btn btn-sm pull-right" />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/btnSave.png" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CssClass="btn btn-sm pull-right" />
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadWindow>
```

and the code behind:

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then
 lblCommentVin.Text = vin
    commentDeptList = SQLData.getAssignedCommentDepartments(Session("user"))

    _departments = New DepartmentRepository().GetAll()
    Session("Departments") = _departments

    For Each dept As String In commentDeptList
        ddlDepartments.Items.Add(New ListItem(dept, dept))
    Next
    ddlDepartments.DataBind()
```

The code stops working where im trying to get the selecteditem

```
 Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    If txtComment.Text.Length > 1 Then
        Dim DepartmentName As String = ddlDepartments.SelectedItem.ToString
```

Comment: In what page event are you running the binding code?

Comment: It is being done on a page Load under the if not isPostBack 'ddlDepartments.DataBind()'